# Replace only leading zeros with space in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace only the leading zeros of the select query.

I am using this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('00015201', '(0)', ' ') 
FROM DUAL;
```

But the result is

```
Column
--------
   152 1
```

I am expecting

```
Column
--------
   15201
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LTRIM` to remove the zeros. Use `LPAD` to put blanks in their places.

```
select lpad(ltrim(numstr, '0'), length(numstr), ' ')
from (select '00015201' as numstr from dual);
```